# Candy Crush Memory Allocation - Large Heap?

Tags: android, memory

I used the following piece of code in my onCreate() method:

```
        ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        Log.d("test", "Memory Class=" + am.getMemoryClass());
        int maxMB = (int) ((Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1024) / 1024);
        Log.d("test", "Memory maxMB=" + maxMB);
        int totalMB = (int) ((Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory() / 1024) / 1024);
        Log.d("test", "Memory totalMB=" + totalMB);
```

which resulted in:
Memory Class: 96MB, 
Max Memory: 96MB, 
Total Memory: 15MB,

Then I installed an app which shows the memory being consumed by "running" apps and I found out that Candy Crush uses 175 MB which is way larger than my the maximum I got (96MB). How is this possible? Does it mean they use the "largeHeap = true" in manifest? All I know is that Android Official Website strictly discourages developers from using this flag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Then I installed an app which shows the memory being consumed by "running" apps and I found out that Candy Crush uses 175 MB which is way larger than my the maximum I got (96MB).

The odds of the author of that app getting it right [are not very good](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298208/how-to-discover-memory-usage-of-my-application-in-android/2299813#2299813). I would use the tools described by Ms. Hackborn and [this Android Developers Blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/01/process-stats-understanding-how-your.html) instead.

> How is this possible? Does it mean they use the "largeHeap = true" in manifest?

That is one possibility. Their app may also not be based much in Java -- game engines are often implemented using the NDK, and NDK allocations are not subject to the Dalvik heap limit.